# How to get properties of image like shadow, mid-tones and highlight in Android? And how to manipulate these properties in Android?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-bitmap

I am not able to get any documentations related to properties like shadow, mid-tones and highlight manipulation of an Image or Bitmap in Android. I will be grateful if you can provide me any documentation or tutorial about it. Thanks in advance for helping.